# Latex macro lists in \foreach

Tags: macros, lists, foreach

I have the following code, where I define two separate lists. I want "foreach" to pick items of these two separate lists. This question is updated to make it clear that "AA" and "BB" are also needed as outputs.

```
\def\mylistAA{11/110,22/220}
\def\mylistBB{111/1110,222/2220}

\foreach \t/\l in{AA/\mylistAA, BB/\mylistBB} {
    \foreach \x/\y in \l {
        this is \x and \y  from list \t \\
    }
}
```

I want this to produce:

```
this is 11 and 110 from list AA
this is 22 and 220 from list AA
this is 111 and 1110 from list BB
this is 222 and 2220 from list BB
```

instead i get:

```
this is 11/110,22/220 and 11/110,22/220 from list AA
this is 111/1110,222/2220 and 111/1110,222/2220 from list BB
```

Could you help me redefine so that I accomplish what I need? Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The desired output can be generated by

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgffor}
\begin{document}
\def\mylistAA{11/110,22/220}
\def\mylistBB{111/1110,222/2220}

\foreach \x/\y in \mylistAA
{this is \x\ and \y  \par}
\foreach \x/\y in \mylistBB
{this is \x\ and \y  \par}
\end{document}
```

[image]

This can be made a nested loop.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgffor}
\begin{document}
\def\mylistAA{11/110,22/220}
\def\mylistBB{111/1110,222/2220}

\foreach \lst in {\mylistAA,\mylistBB}
{\edef\Lst{\lst}
\foreach \x/\y in \Lst
{this is \x\ and \y  \par}}
\end{document}
```

[image]

I left out the `AA/` and `BB/` whose purpose I do not understand. (The `\edef` trick seems to be important here.)

Comment: Thank you very much. For my purposes the second version would be the closest to what I need. However while AA and BB have no use in this minimal example, they are actually needed in the real code. They provide text (caption) to the figures that the code will generate. I will attempt to expand on your second example. However, if you or anybody has suggestions, I would appreciate it! I will edit my post to make it clear that those AA and BB are also needed.

Answer (score 1):

It took a trivial extension to the solution proposed by marmot to include the other part of macro as well (AA and BB). Here I am posting the version that works, based on solution proposed above:

```
\def\mylistAA{11/110,22/220}
\def\mylistBB{111/1110,222/2220}

\foreach \t/\l in{AA/\mylistAA, BB/\mylistBB} {
    \edef\Lst{\l}
    \foreach \x/\y in \Lst {
        this is \x and \y  from list \t \\
    }
}
```